# React-hook-form's register function is showing Type argument cannot be inferred from usage error in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am building a React JS application and I am using React hook form plugin for handling form input values, https://react-hook-form.com/. I am using it with TypeScript. But it is showing me an error.

This is my code.

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

type LoginForm = {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}


export const Login = () => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm<LoginForm>();
    const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

    return (
        /* "handleSubmit" will validate your inputs before invoking "onSubmit" */
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            {/* register your input into the hook by invoking the "register" function */}
            <input defaultValue="test" {...register("email")} />

            {/* include validation with required or other standard HTML validation rules */}
            <input {...register("password", { required: true })} />
            {/* errors will return when field validation fails  */}
            {errors.password && <span>This field is required</span>}

            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    );
}
```

In the IDE, the register function is showing this error.

```
Type argument cannot be inferred from usage
```

[image]

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://tsplay.dev/Nr9v3w What IDE and version do you use? Library version? TS version?

Comment: I am using latest react JS installed using Vite (just installed or setup the project today). Latest react-hook-form package. My IDE is webstorm.

Comment: I upgraded my webstorm. Also, I re-installed npm modules after that. It's now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart your IDE , sometimes it bugs out after a fresh install